# Image optimization pipeline?

Tags: photoshop, image-optimization, jpegtran

Once I have finalized edits, if I’m planning to run my photos through something like ImageOptim, how should I save my photos in photoshop? Do I use save for web at 72 ppi and high compression, or should I save photos at their highest quality before running them through ImageOptim; i.e. high ppi and quality at 100%?

Also, within ImageOptim, should I be using jpegoptim, jpegrecompress, or jpegtran? Or a combination of them?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: No idea where you are coming at this from, but if you value your images at all you should shoot in RAW mode and save after processing as native Photoshop PSD files.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I definitely do that, I’m just trying to figure out what to do once the images are finalized and ready to go online.

Comment: It kind of depends on your OS, and what size (in kB) you want your images, and how many you have. I only make PSD files of the highest quality in Photoshop then I run a little script using **GNU Parallel** or **ImageMagick** to size the images down, centre them on a background, insert copyright, strip metadata and optimise them.